# How to implement List interface in this assignment?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, interface, linked-list

Hey so I have and assignment due soon and one of the questions I have is really messing with my head. 
Here it is:

> Implement the following methods in the two implementations (called
>   MyArrayList and MyLinkedList) of List interface:
>
> Boolean   add(E e), void add(int index,E element), void  clear(), E 
>   remove(int index), Boolean remove(Object String  toString(), int size()
>
> Define your classes to be generics. The array implementation should
>   have dynamic resizing (double the size when growing and halve the size
>   when less than 25 % of the capacity is used) and the linked list
>   implementation should use doubly linked list. Also, the behavior of
>   these methods should be equivalent to that of Java Standard Library’s
>   classes ArrayList or LinkedList. For the rest of the methods of the
>   List interface, you may just throw an exception.

So what I don't understand is, if they want me to use the 'List' interface in java, why do they want me to implement the methods if these methods are already implemented in the List interface.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: If you take a look at the `List` interface you'll see they are **defined**, but not **implemented**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods are not **implemented** in the interface, they are **defined** by it. It's up to you to provide concrete implementations for these method definitions in two ways - once based on an array, and once with doubly linked list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this means i'll have to do all the work of writing a node class, and then implement these methods ?

Comment: what i mean is, what's the use of adding the list interface if i have to implement the methods myself ?

Comment: @Qwerty0987 the main use is that you can then pass your classes to any method that expects a `List`, e.g., `Collections.sort`.